# What is the preferable way to define ADT in Scala - OO vs FP

Tags: scala, functional-programming

After some discussions i would like to **emphasise**, that the question is related of using inheritance as in OOP over Product/Sum type as in FP or vice versa. What you prefer and what are your suggestions! So...

I have some doubts - what is the cleaner (clearer) way to define the following:

For example I prefer

```
sealed trait Shape

case class Square(length: Int) extends Shape
case class Rhombus(length: Int) extends Shape
```

instead of

```
sealed abstract class Shape(val length: Int)

case class Square(override val length: Int) extends Shape(length)
case class Rhombus(override val length: Int) extends Shape(length)
```

but then

```
def draw(shape: Shape): String = shape match {
  case Square(length) => length.toString
  case Rhombus(length) => length.toString
}
```

instead of

```
def draw(shape: Shape): String = shape.length.toString
```

Definition of the types looks in the first approach less verbose and more consistent but if i need to have a generic logic for all shapes, like `draw` method, second approach looks clearer.

Comment: It depends IMO. If you have more operations that are going to be done globally on common fields between classes, use the latter `draw`. If you actually need to separate logic by type, use the former.

Comment: There's also `sealed trait Shape { def length: Int }`

Comment: Hi @Reactormonk! It's not bad suggestion, but for me it's more inheritance over Product type. With `trait` it's maybe more a mixin, but still! `length` is then a part of all shapes even if you don't need it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Scala doesn't have sum types, inheritance *is* how you implement sum types in Scala, so the question of "inheritance or sum types* doesn't make much sense, IMO.

Comment: @JörgWMittag as well as ad-hoc polymorphism, but still implicits gives you way to fill like it is ad-hoc. The same way if you have `sealed trait Shape` without any state, and you define `case class Square extends Shape` and `case class Rhombus extends Shape`, then Shape is Square |  Rhombus (sum - Square **OR** Rhombus)... `case class Square(length: Int, angel: Int)` then Square is Int **AND** Int (product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this book https://leanpub.com/fpmortals/

> We can also use a `sealed trait` in place of a `sealed abstract class` but there are binary compatibility advantages to using `abstract class`. A `sealed trait` is only needed if you need to create a complicated ADT with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

This would be the prefered way:

```
sealed trait Shape {
  def length: Int
}

case class Square(length: Int) extends Shape
case class Rhombus(length: Int) extends Shape
```

Here are the few non-idiomatic things in your code:

- `abstract class` are primarely a java compatibility thing, use traits when possible
- `override` a non implemented field feels wrong
- `val` in interfaces should be avoided, always use `defs` for the abstract, these can be refined with something else

Comment: i think that this way is the correct one as well, but as @Reactormonk commented `def length: Int` can be defined in `trait Shape`, in this case you don't have pitfalls that you mentioned... but still it fills bad!

Comment: @Reactormonk what's about Java? nor sure i understood your comment.

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain, @Reactormonk i would like to have FP way with `trait` only as a product type and then Square OR Rhombus. Another way is OO way with `trait` as parent and Square/Rhombus as children. The thing you mentioned are indeed correct, but doesn't give an answer to my dilemma!

Comment: If you don't want to use inheritance it doesn't get any better that your first example.

Comment: Yes! And the question is, should it be better not how! And if you think so, then why?)

Comment: Its not about to create a semantically the same code, but do it "better"=)

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain or is your point is if it's `trait` with `def` it's the best way to go?

Comment: Your original question was about what's idiomatic, I've answered that. If you are asking for opinion, SO is not the correct place.

Comment: hm, i'm don't agree that your way to define an ADT is idiomatic! but still thank you for an opinion and the solution

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain do we both mean by ADT - Algebraic Data Type?

Comment: Yes. Idiomatic is not about opinions, please google "Scala ADT".

Comment: 100 %, here is my point: is in the level of trait def or val or something else is used? As in your example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143984/discussion-between-iuriisusuk-and-olivierblanvillain).

Answer (score 0):

> It's not bad suggestion, but for me it's more inheritance over Product type. With trait it's maybe more a mixin, but still! length is then a part of all shapes even if you don't need it.

If you don't need it for all shapes, then you can't have

```
def draw(shape: Shape): String = shape.length.toString
```

in the first place, and not getting it isn't a drawback. But you can also have

```
sealed trait Shape
sealed trait HasLength extends Shape {
  def length: Int
}

// Shape optional, but may be clearer for this case
case class Square(length: Int) extends Shape with HasLength
case class Rhombus(length: Int) extends Shape with HasLength

def draw(shape: Shape): String = shape match {
  case shape: HasLength => shape.length.toString
  case ... => ... // handle those shapes which don't have length
}
```